# Designing a catalyst for use in catalytically hypergolic fuel mixtures using nitrous oxide

Tags: engine-design, fuel-system, hydrogen-peroxide, nitrous-oxide

The use of hydrogen peroxide with hydrocarbons such as RP1 has long been a popular choice, not least of all for its hypergolic properties when paired with a catalyst bed. This motor design, catalysing the oxidiser before it enters the combustion chamber, improves combustion stability and removes the need for an ignition source, and so I myself have tried(being the operative word) to design something similar to this. Unfortunately while I am aware of the workings of a rocket motor, I have no clue what the design parameters of a catalyst might be, especially one with the requirements a rocket engine entails. So, my question is:
***what are the parameters of catalyst in other rocket engines, and are there any generalised design parameters that could be followed, such as the structure, type, and volume/amount of catalyst required?***

Assume also that the catalyst is designed for a nitrous oxide/propane propellant mixture, using inexpensive and obtainable catalysts such as copper chloride. Safety is not a huge concern as this is a theoretical motor, and its importance is secondary.

Question in part inspired by a paper on the DOP(nitrous oxide/propane) propellant mixture: https://tfaws.nasa.gov/TFAWS06/Proceedings/Aerothermal-Propulsion/Papers/TFAWS06-1026_Paper_Herdy.pdf